# Select fields with SQL statement inside CommandText, c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, winforms

So i would like to select specific fields from 2 tables and show them inside a `datagrid`, so i'm using inner join with ID matched from 2 tables, and i want to select fields when the `textbox` value (txtTelephone) is equal to a number inside my table.

Here is my code:

```
    private void buttonSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("*some connection info*");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "from C in Contact join P in Phones on C.[ID Επαφής] equals P.[ID Επαφής] where (P.Αριθμός = ('"+txtTelephone.Text+"')) select new {C.Επώνυμο, C.Όνομα, C.[Ημ. Γέννησης], P.[Περιγραφή Τηλεφώνου], P.Αριθμός}";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I think you might be mixing `linq` with `sql` -- your `commandtext` should be a `select` statement...

Comment: SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc... are only for MS SQL Server, aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CommandText`need a SQL Statement like

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FROM table WHERE id = @PAR"
```

you should also consider using [SQlCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) to pass `txtTelephone.Text` to your query.